# Notice-Updated div moving around unprompted

Tags: jquery, wp-admin, admin-css

I have a `div.notice.updated` that is moving on the DOM and I can't locate the code that's doing that. Disabled all plugins and changed to a default theme without results.

I'm printing the element on the main content block and it jumps to the sidebar after the page finishes loading (it's clearly jQuery in action):

```
<div class="notice updated">Form sent</div>
```

<kbd>[image: result of the error]</kbd>

I'm using [Frank Bueltge's Admin Style plugin](https://github.com/bueltge/wordpress-admin-style) to get standard WP HTML code for the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `.notice` on WP source code I found the culprit at [**`wp-admin/js/common.js`**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/js/common.js?rev=42411#L734):

```
$( 'div.updated, div.error, div.notice' ).not( '.inline, .below-h2' ).insertAfter( $headerEnd );
```

Adding an `inline` class to my code solves the issue:

```
<div class="notice updated inline">Form sent</div>
```

Comment: Did you edit the WP core?

Comment: @Tony, no, not at all. I added a link to the code in the Core in my answer